# How to read pdf and store values from it into database in laravel?

Tags: laravel, pdftotext

I am using **spatie/pdf-to-text** to read pdf with the help of below link

[link of spatie pdf to text in github](https://github.com/spatie/pdf-to-text)

But its not working for me in laravel.

It shows me error:

`The command ""/usr/bin/pdftotext" C:\Users\payment.pdf -" failed.\n\nExit Code: -1073741515(Unknown error)\n\nWorking directory: C:\xampp\htdocs\admin_site\public\n\nOutput:\n================\n\n\nError Output:\n================\n"` in console.

I found lots of solutions but not getting any idea so finally think to put it here.

In my laravel controller :

`$text = (new Pdf())
->setPdf('C:\Users\payment.pdf')
->text();
echo Pdf::getText('C:\Users\payment.pdf');die();`

it show nothing except above error message.
can you guys help me out to solve this problem with above link.
Or please let me know about some other libraries that are working to read pdf that is uploaded by user and get values that we want and store that values into database.

Comment: Sorry but I must ask the obvious, you do have pdftotext, right? Did you try running it from the command prompt (given the path you give I assume you're on Windows)?

Comment: Nop i dont try it yet with command prompt

Comment: In that case I first advice you to try it from the command prompt, maybe is not a problem with your PHP but with pdftotext and/or the path to the file